# PowerShell - Pass array as an optional parameter value

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to PowerShell.

I'm trying to pass an array of server names as an optional parameter value to get the last bootup time for a list of servers.

**Example 1**

```
$serverList = @('server1"', '"server2"', '"server3"', '"server4"', '"server5"')

Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $serverList -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime
```

**Example 2**

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName server1,server2,server3,server4,server5 -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime
```

- In example 1, I get an error that says it can't connect to the
  servers.
- In example 2, it works.

I'm likely missing a key piece of fundamental knowledge as to why what I'm doing wasn't working.  What am I missing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to clean up the quoting. Your first element: `'server1"'`; others: `'"server2"'`. `'server1'` or `"server1"` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, that did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example you are over-doing things with the quotes. (also `server1` has an ending double quote, but no starting double quote..)

By putting the servers inside single quotes `'`, the text inside it is taken literally, so you are feeding the cmdlet with names like `"server2"`, so **including** the double-qoute characters.
These quotes obviously don't belong to the server name.

BTW: Not an error, but you don't need the `@()` when creating the server names array.

This would be a better way of setting up your string array, where you can use either single or double quote characters, but not both:

```
$serverList = 'server1', 'server2', 'server3', 'server4', 'server5'
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $serverList -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime
```

You have also noticed that when used as parameters to a cmdlet, you don't even need the quotes, and the elements are interpreted as strings, as long as they do not contain space characters:

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName server1,server2,server3,server4,server5 -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | Select-Object csname, lastbootuptime
```